# Microsoft 365 Developer Program

Tags: microsoft365

when I create a microsoft developer account for microsoft 365 subscription,I get a mail that I do not qualify to be a developer. What are the qualification??

I tried to create an account using a different mail address but did not work

Answer (score 0):

This is because Microsoft suspends creating new free E5 tenants for users. Yes, Microsoft clarified that only users with Visual Studio Enterprise subscriptions are eligible to create free developer tenants. If you don't have one, you are advised to purchase a paid plan for testing purposes.